# Trigger the Mobile Browsers Back button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a website where a child route gets rendered in the parent route, to add the styles and other details a **Boolean** state is passed to the **outlook**, so that the child route slides in from the left side of the screen and then get renders.

Previously I had another problem on rendering the child route properly. At that time when I manually refreshed the **pin-details**(child-route), the page would not get rendered only because the Boolean state was null which was passed down from the parent route.

Right now I have fixed manual refresh problem, but encountered a similar problem, which is if I press the back button (default mobile app-bar button) NOTE: - not browser back button. The Boolean state stays true, and browser navigates to previous page, but does not get displayed all because of the state.

My current approach is to target the browser back button and sets the Boolean state set to false once pressing on it.

I'm not quite sure on how to implement this or where to start.
Do tell me if this approach is good!

Do not want to make the question messy by adding a lot of code, for now im sharing my website, check it. [here](http://upshare-aniketlodh.netlify.app/)

**Feed.jsx**

```
    const [renderChildren, setRenderChildren] = useState(false);
    
    {/*Pin layout*/}
        <section>
            {feed_data.map((item, index) => (
                <Pins pin={item} setRenderChildren={setRenderChildren}/> {/* We can manipulate the state from the child route. */}
            ))}
        </section>

    
    {/*Loading the PinDetails section*/}
        <section
            className={`${renderChildren ? "left-0" : "left-full"} fixed top-0 bg-white w-full z-30 transition-all h-full overflow-y-auto`}>
            <Outlet context={[renderChildren, setRenderChildren]}/>
        </section>
```

[My Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-haze-1q337s?file=/src/PinDetails.jsx)

Answer (score 0):

To disable the back button and prevent the user to going back of the page,

In you javascript(*App.js*). You can include this.

```
import React, {Component, useEffect} from 'react';

useEffect(() => {
      const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => true)
      return () => backHandler.remove()
    }
```

You can also [check this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/preventing-going-back/) on how this *useEffect* works.

**Additional**

In order to disable swipe back of screen, add this in your auuthentication main screen.

```
<AuthStack.Screen
   name= //Name of main app(ex:"Home")
   component= //Name of main component(ex:{Home})
   options={{ gestureEnabled:false }}
/>
```

Or using *beforeRemove*

```
React.useEffect(() =>
 navigation.addListener('beforeRemove',(e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  )
 }
);
```

Dont forget the ***import*** *from* ***'react'***.

Comment: there are some limitations using this. for example, if user back swipes, then this will not be called. what to do then!

Comment: Do you read the given documentation? It said *Disable the swipe gesture for the screen ( **gestureEnabled: false** )* Or, *Sometimes you may want to prevent the user from leaving a screen, for example, if there are unsaved changes, you might want to show a confirmation dialog. You can achieve it by using the **beforeRemove** event.*

Comment: yes, got it what you are trying to say. But it seems similar approach doesnot exist for ReactJs, which im currently using to build the project.

Comment: I can't judge what is the problem depend on your situation. Better to provide some of your code or make playground so it can be easily check.

Comment: i did provide you the website to check the problem. To re-create the problem you can just click on any image in the feed section, once the pin details route slides in from right to left, you can press the back button, and then problem will arise.  Besides that, I'm don't think there is any code problem/bug in my code. I'm still adding snippet of the code logic which is triggering the pin-details route.

Comment: I already check the site, but the problem is how can i check the code you are using? if it same syntax, then why the above code/answer doesn't working on yours? i already try and yes it doesn't work, so how can i give you a suggestion on what part of your code will change or will be changed? *i need some of your relational code

Comment: I just edit my answer.

Comment: okey, i will provide you something similar to my website section. Maybe that will help you to understand.

Comment: Update I have edited my question and added Sandbox link where you can actually re create the original problem.